# Adding to kill-buffer-hook results in "setq: Wrong type argument"

Tags: hooks, file-local-variables, buffer-local, kill-buffer, defun

Subtract a buffer's (the file's) size from a variable before killing it. Emacs 26.

```
(defvar cumulative-open-bytes '0 )

(defun buffer-settings-calc-bytes ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-open-file-size (file-attribute-size (file-attributes buffer-file-name))))
    (setq cumulative-open-bytes (- current-open-file-size cumulative-open-bytes))
    (message (propertize (format "Cumulative Open Bytes: (%d) after closing %s (%d bytes)." 
                                  cumulative-open-bytes buffer-file-name current-open-file-size) 
                         'face 'warning))))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'buffer-settings-calc-bytes)
```

Results in the following message:
**setq: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil**
This appears just after the string message from the function.

I have tried `setq` in place of the `let`, and removing `interactive`.
Emacs will not load with the above, and evaluating it in place breaks
most navigation and buffer features.

Notably `toggle-debug-on-error`.

The following also appears invoking arbitrary commands in addition to the above:
**Error running timer: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)**

Is this a local binding issue? How should this hook be set?

Comment: Um, where do you get `file-attribute-size` from?  This isn't defined here on Emacs 25.1.

Comment: Emacs 26.0.50.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that you try to use a non-number when subtracting numbers, more specifically `nil`.  Your code assumes `buffer-file-name` always returns a file name pointing to a file you can query the attributes from which is wrong, buffers don't have to point at files and can return `nil` in this case.  Your hook must handle this case to not error out prematurely:

```
(defvar my-cumulative-open-bytes 0)

(defun my-buffer-settings-calc-bytes ()
  (let ((size (nth 7 (file-attributes buffer-file-name))))
    (when size
      (setq my-cumulative-open-bytes (- size my-cumulative-open-bytes))
      (message
       (propertize
        (format "Cumulative Open Bytes: (%d) after closing %s (%d bytes)."
                my-cumulative-open-bytes buffer-file-name size)
        'face 'warning)))))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook 'my-buffer-settings-calc-bytes)
```

PS: This hook might slow down your Emacs as it's run when every single temporary buffer is killed, so consider achieving your goal in a different way.

Comment: That's a really good point. I appreciate the insight.